# UITableView or UICollectionView for simple Siri like user experience

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I am a newbie to Swift and trying to develop something like Siri user experience. A step by step explanation,

- User ask a question to perform an action which will be displayed on top right of the screen
- App responses to the question right below the question and on top left of the screen
- When a user asks a question again, I'll clear the existing conversation and place on top right of the screen
- If the user doesn't asks a question, I need to request the user to ask some question which is placed on top left

I am planning to do develop above user experience. Which is the best way i.e., UITableView or UICollectionView or Simple UITextView by programmatically adding it?

I read about UICollectionView and UITableView, they are really useful when you build some thing like messaging experience and has some action like reply, delete, archive, etc. **In my case, it is just a string comes and goes off so I think UITextView would be much better**.

What do you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

Conversational data is almost always better suited by a table view. Siri likely uses a table view as well given its cell based design which is very evident in older versions of the UI:
[image: Old siri UI]